# Communication between ROS and Optitrack

Tags: ros, communication, optitrack, mocap-optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am new to ROS and I needed some help/guidance. I am using ROS(Fuerte) on a Virtual Machine. I am trying to understand how to transmit data(coordinates of a bot) from Optitrack(NatNet), installed on a different machine, to ROS (on a separate machine). I wish to understand this myself so if anyone can guide me or provide me with links to understand this, I would appreciate it. Please let me know if any other information is required from me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54255/communication-between-ros-and-optitrack/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
Hello @nemesis how did you solve I am getting the same error like you used to get. Can you tell me how u were able to solve it?

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2017-06-27**:
@UbuntuROs I already have an answer to this question.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
Can you help me in solving the error? This is the steps I followed to connect Motive with Ros

1. I git clone the file from https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/vrpn_client_ros
2. exported it using the export command  export VRPN_ROOT=path to where VRPN is located
   3.install the necessary package

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
4.Run  catkin_make
5. Launch using $roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server:=239.255.42.99
when i ran it, it says the connection is established but when i tried to run $rostopic command it says that the topic didnt established yet. What did I get wrong? I really need your help.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
Can you guide me through on how to create a connection between motive and ROS? I appreciate your help.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-28**:
@nemesis did u use Natnet or VRPN?

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-28**:
@nemesis what is the link I opened https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/ but there are many files over there which specifically did u use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using this post/answer to describe the procedure I followed, as a reference in case someone else has an issue -

@balto -

1. In the "workspace" folder that you generally create (given in ROS tutorials) I used to the command "svn co *link*" to get/download the ros_vrpn_client.
   The *link* here refers to the gt-ros-pkg repository (I can't post the exact link right now because of low karma points)
2. Now, using either "rosdep install ros_vrpn_client" or "rosmake ros_vrpn_client" I "built" the package (this is where I was confused, what exactly to use)
3. Just in case, I used the "source ~/workspace/setup.bash" command after building the package.
4. go to the ros_vrpn_client/ folder and execute the install_vrpn.sh file (command line -> go to folder containing file -> ./install_vrpn.sh )
5. Start streaming in Tracking Tools after creating the trackable.
6. runs "roscore" and in a separate terminal run the command given on the ros_vrpn_client wiki page (to run the node).

**Issues**

a) I got the error - "from Trackable1: No response from server" (This was because of an ip address problem)

b) Upon putting the correct address I got the same issue *but* this time I also got the message which notified me of a difference in version (7_28 and 7_20). I assumed that there is a connection with the server although no data is being sent.

c) As per your suggestion I changed the name of the trackable to "Tracker" in both: Tracking Tools as well as in the rosrun command. There is no "error" mentioning "No response from server" anymore but there is still the message about the different versions. After displaying this message, it shows nothing (and doesn't end either). So I dunno how to proceed. Or is there some other way to view the data that is being transmitted on these nodes??

**Note - ** In a separate terminal I used "rostopic echo /Tracker/pose" and I think it's displaying the coordinates correctly. Thank you so much for your time and help :)

@Ryan -

I downloaded and built the mocap_optitrack package in a similar manner like I have explained above. I faced the following issues after running the "rosrun mocap_optitrack mocap_node" command.

**Issues**

It displays a bunch of lines starting with [Info] and the last line mentioning "Enabling non blocking I/O". I initially thought it was because of the address given in the "Multicast Interface" under Streaming Properties of the Tracking Tools software. I tried changing it to some other address but it doesn't give me anything else either.
Is there something that needs to be set separately? Like setting a particular Port in this case or something else?
Or is there some other way to view the data that is being transmitted on these nodes??

**Note -**
In Tracking Tools put the "Multicast Interface" address as the IP address of the system you have your ROS on. You can then display the coordinates using
"rostopic echo /Husky_1/pose".
I am still nto sure why it's called "Husky_1" instead of the name "Tracker" that I assigned in Tracking Tools.

Can you anyone comment on a difference between the two (VRPN and mocap)?

Please remember that I am running ROS via a virtual machine.

Please edit anything that you think is wrong above (so that others don't face issues later on)

---

Originally posted by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) with karma: 237 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-10**:
Yes, our method uses Tracking Tools

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-19**:
We use mocap_optitrack with a virtual machine as well. I will point another person on our team to this thread.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-02-19**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-19**:
Good to hear.  Is all working now?

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-02-21**:
@balto - Yes! I think I will just have to modify the code a little bit to match with my Tracking Tools results - The axes are bit different; and get Yaw,Pitch,Roll as outputs too. That should be possible right?
@Ryan - Apart from a certain variation, mocap is working for me too. Thanks!

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-02-26**:
Anybody uses Motive? I think Tracking Tools is outdated.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-02-27**:
Motive works with NatNet great.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-02-27**:
Do you mean I can just rosmake mocap_optitrack and the node will works perfectly with the latest Motive software? Does Motive use the latest NatNet? Then it should transmit data in a different format, like having more fields. Am I wrong?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-02-28**:
Well, mocap_optitrack has been catkinized but yes, it was always meant to work with NatNet.  I don't believe there have been many updates to NatNet.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-03-03**:
Nice! How do you feel about OptiTrack? Are you satisfied about the performance like latency, stability and resolution?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-03-04**:
I believe it works quite well.  I wish it could all run on linux so the latency would be reduced but with wired connection is does what I need.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-29**:
Hey I was running $rosrun mocap_optitrack mocap_node command but keeps getting "Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311]. Retrying....." Why is that am getting this message? Can anyone help me please?

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-07-13**:
@nemesis Did you use a virtual machine to run Ubuntu or did you use another PC with Linux OS?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you need to use NatNet?  I use VRPN with OptiTrack system which is documented here: http: //www.ros.org/wiki/ros_vrpn_client

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-11**:
Sure. Did you download the package?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-11**:
@Ryan is the mocap_optitrack able to work with ROS electric? Since I noticed it was for the Husky, I assume it is on groovy.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-19**:
@nemesis Setup the tracking tools to broadcast the pose and name the trackable "Tracker". Then run the ROS command.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-04**:
@balto - I don't know if I should start a separate post for this or not, but, how can I get the node to display the "Yaw,Pitch & Roll" instead of the Quartenions?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-04**:
You must convert them using the bullet commands something like this: tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->transform.rotation, q);
btMatrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll,pitch,yaw);

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-04**:
You must convert them using the bullet commands something like this:

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-06**:
@balto - Oh ok. The code is bit confusing (not used to all of this), so still trying to figure out how to go about "implementing" what you mentioned above.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-09**:
Is that a question? I can send you a more detailed snippet of code if you want.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-11**:
@balto - Yes, that would be quite helpful. Thank you!
I tried something similar to what you described above in a comment. But the output wasn't quite right..

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-18**:
void poseCallback(const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
{

curr_Pose[0] = msg->transform.translation.x;
curr_Pose[1] = msg->transform.translation.y;
curr_Pose[2] = msg->transform.translation.z;
tf::Quaternion q;
double roll,pitch, yaw;
tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->transfo

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-18**:
rm.rotation, q);
btMatrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll,pitch,yaw);
curr_Pose[3] = roll;
curr_Pose[4] = pitch;
curr_Pose[5] = yaw;

}

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-18**:
@balto - Thank you! Just to confirm, this code is supposed to be an extension of the source code of the ros_vrpn_client? 'Cause I tried adding this code and used "Make" but it gave me back some errors. And thank you for being patient with me! Appreciate it!

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-19**:
I use: #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include 
#include 
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vrpn_Connection.h>

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-03-19**:
#include <vrpn_Tracker.h>
#include <LinearMath/btQuaternion.h>

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-19**:
@balto - Thanks! Errors that I get - no matching function for call to 'btMatrix3x3::btMatrix3x3(tf::Quaternion&)'. Also mentions that curr_Pose is not declared (understandable). And apart from this it shows "Notes" mentioning something like "candidate expects 9 arguments, 1 provided".

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-20**:
@balto - If you don't mind, please refer to this - http://answers.ros.org/question/58742/quaternion-to-roll-pitch-yaw/
I created a separate post all together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use [mocap_optitrack](http://ros.org/wiki/mocap_optitrack) with NatNet. A more full-featured and stable version that publishes poses, odometry, and tfs is [here](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/mocap_optitrack), but we haven't updated the ROS wiki to point to it yet.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-28**:
Wiki updated: http://www.ros.org/wiki/mocap_optitrack